# centering Text inside an SVG Triangle in a robust way

Tags: css, svg

How would you modify code-related in order to:

- center text (of different lengths) horizontally inside the triangle
- center text (of different lengths) vertically inside the triangle

...such that the centering is relatively robust (e.g. works in different screen-sizes/browsers, fulfills responsiveness)?

```css
.triangle_ball {
 position:relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 400px;
 top:15px;
  
}

.triangle {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #888888;
  stroke-width: 1;
  d: path("M200 0 L400 346 L0 346 Z");  
}


svg {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
  <div class="triangle_ball">
   <svg width="400px" height="400px" version="1.1">
    <path class="triangle"> </path>
      
      <path id="path1" d="m145,240 h145"/>   
      
      
        <text font-size="25" font-family="sans-serif" fill="#ff5722"> 
  
          <textPath xlink:href="#path1"><tspan fill-opacity="0"><animate attributeName="fill-opacity" values="1" />Text </tspan>
        </textPath> 

        
        </text>       
      
      
      <div class="ball"></div>
   </svg>
     
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider the triangle as background then you can easily center the text using any CSS technique:

```css
.box {
 background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 347" ><path d="M200 0 L400 346 L0 346 Z"  stroke="%23888" fill="transparent" /></svg>') center/100% 100%;
 width:50%;
 color:red;
 font-size:35px;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
 
 border:1px dotted green;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  padding-top:86.6%; /* sqrt(3)/2*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box">some text</div>
```

And if you really want the center of the triangle you can adjust like below:

```css
.box {
 background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 347" ><path d="M200 0 L400 346 L0 346 Z"  stroke="%23888" fill="transparent" /></svg>') center/100% 100%;
 width:50%;
 color:red;
 font-size:35px;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 
}
.box:before{
  content:"";
  padding-top:86.6%; /* sqrt(3)/2*/
}

.box span {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column
}
.box span:before {
  content:"";
  flex-grow:2;
}
.box span:after {
  content:"";
  flex-grow:1;
}

/* To illustrate the centering*/
.box {
 position:relative;
 border:1px dotted green; 
}
.box:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) center/1px 100% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top right,transparent calc(50% - 1px), blue calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 1px),transparent calc(50% + 1px)) bottom/100% 66% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top left,transparent calc(50% - 1px), blue calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 1px),transparent calc(50% + 1px)) bottom/100% 66% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><span>some text</span></div>
```